# OSX - Android Emulator closed because of an internal error:

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-emulator

Trying to run an emulator via a fresh install of Android Studio on a new MacBook Pro and the emulator fails to start with the error message below.

I have attempted re-installing HAXM, re-installing Android Studio, creating a new AVD - all with no luck.

Has anyone experienced this issue and found a fix?

[image]